# mongo C# V2: When and how much of an document is loaded/deserialized especially nested documents

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

While investigate an Exception caused while doing a FindAsync operation [Exception caused while doing a FindAsync operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809891/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-v2-exception-in-findasync-after-updating-nested-collecti)

It looks like during the FindAsync the found Objects are deserialized. Which does mean, that the whole documents are loaded into memory.

But if I only want to access one entry of a nested list of subdocuments this doesn't make sense if the embedded list is large. Is there away to prevent loading of the whole document?

Does it make a difference how the loading is done if I use BSONDocument or a strongly typed collection?

The same goes for adding new embedded entries to the document (e.g. time stamps). Will for adding/updating always the whole document be loaded?

Comment: Unless you specify otherwise.. the whole object is retrieved. It doesn't matter whether it's typed or `BsonDocument`.

Comment: How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: Depends on how you query. But you can use `Project` to select only part of the document.

Comment: Ah, so Project is handled on the server side? I will have to have a closer look on Projection. I didn't realize to use them in this context.

Comment: But what about Updates and adding Data?